# How can I optimize the rendering of a graph while preserving the shape?

Tags: java, optimization, dataset, rendering, graphing

I've been writing a program to graph datapoints in Java. I need a lots of flexibility and speed so I don't want to use an existing library as much as possible. Right now, it essentially uses Graphics2D to draw lines and dots representing the points in a file of data.

**My problem is,** some of my datasets have upwards of 100,000 points.When it is going to be rendered with all full drag/zoom functionality, it is getting quite slow.

**My question is,** how can I reduce this dataset or make a simplification of it so that I can display the graph without changing the overall shape?

I could only draw every third point, for instance, but what if that skipped over and didn't display an important outlier? I could try averaging groups of points, but that could have the same problem.

And for services like Google Finance, where they probably have millions of points to display, how do they deal with this?

Comment: You could consider [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) or [JGraphX](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx)

Comment: The phrase you need to search for is "Quantization," "the procedure of constraining something from a continuous set of values to a relatively small discrete set" - wikipedia

Comment: Thanks Devon, that's the keyword I needed, couldn't find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check for range differences between points before rendering them.  Give them a threshold that they need to stay within in order to not be re-rendered.